# Php multiple different regexp

Tags: php, arrays, regex, object, explode

This code is running successfully. $array[1] returned column name.

```
//My String
$string = '<input value="{#Quantity#}" type="number" />';
preg_match_all('/{#(.*)#\}/i', $text, $array);
print_r($array);
/*
Returned : 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {#Quantity#}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Quantity
        )

)
*/
```

But if there are more column name in text. It is not working :

```
$string = '<input value="{#Quantity#}" data-id="{#Id#}" type="number" />';
preg_match_all('/{#(.*)#\}/i', $text, $array);
print_r($array);
/*
Returned : 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {#Quantity#}" data-id="{#Id#}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Quantity#}" data-id="{#Id
        )

)
*/
```

I want to this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {#Quantity#}" data-id="{#Id#}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
             [0] => Quantity
             [1] => Id
        )

)
```

How should the regexp be ?
So, How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the text to `$string` variable and then in `preg_match_all`
 you are using `$text`.
I'm guessing that is just a typo?

Now for the other part of the problem. You should use non greedy match. Adding `?` after your `.*` makes the match non-greedy - stopping at the shortest match.

if you use `preg_match_all('/{#(.*?)#\}/', $string, $array);`
then $array should be this. Is that what you are after?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {#Quantity#}
        [1] => {#Id#}
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Quantity
        [1] => Id
    )

)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but isn't the `i`-switch kinda redundant in this expression?

Comment: In this simple case it makes negligible difference. But using lazy matching is a performance hit. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy for an explanation of why

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are correct, will edit the answer and remove that.

Comment: @Luke you are also correct. I just added to what he already had and went for the simplest (but not most performant) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the RegEx: `'/{#([^}]*)#\}/'`

Instead of repeatedly matching `.` (any character), you should look for `[^}]` which is "any character except `}`" as `}` is where you want to stop matching.

```
Match 1
Full match  14-26   `{#Quantity#}`
Group 1.    16-24   `Quantity`

Match 2
Full match  37-43   `{#Id#}`
Group 1.    39-41   `Id`
```